# Displaying data from a file in a TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, file, javafx, io, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create a simple ToDo app in JavaFX. All the data that a user enters is written to a txt file and then read from that file and displayed in a TableView.
The TableView has three columns, where the first represents the Name of the user, the second displays Date, and the third shows Additional info. When user enters data into three columns, a Value class is created from three parameters(String name, String date, String additionalInfo) that user entered and stored in a file.

Data is written to file using this method:

```
  public void updateFile() {
       //Deleting a file and creating a new one to update data
        if (myFile.delete()) {
            System.out.println("File deleted");
        }
        try {
            if (myFile.createNewFile())
                System.out.println("File created");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       //going through user's data
        for(int i = 0; i<arrList.size(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j< arrList.get(i).size();j++){
                stringBuilder.append(arrList.get(i).get(j)+"\n");
            }
        }

        try {
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("file.txt");
            myWriter.write(stringBuilder.toString());
            myWriter.close();
            blankLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green");
            blankLabel.setText("Saved");
            LabelAnimation la = new LabelAnimation(blankLabel, 3);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Let's say a user enters into a Name TextField:

```
John Overflow
```

into a Date TextField:

```
12.02.2021
```

and finally enters into Additional Info TextField:

```
YAY!
```

The file will contain values:

```
John Overflow
12.02.2021
YAY!
```

So, the values entered are stored line by line in a file
Now, when I want to display values from the file, I invoke the following method:

```
  public void setTableViewFromFile(){

            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);

                while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                   String name = sc.nextLine();//Name
                    String date = sc.nextLine();//Date
                    String info = sc.nextLine();//Additional Info

                    Value value = new Value(name, date, info);
                    tableView.getItems().add(value);

                    storeValue();//stores value in an ArrayList of values
                }


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This implementation works fine for one line Strings, but doesn't work in case if the user enters "\n"(new line) into AdditionalInfo TextField since this new line will be treated as a separate parameter for Value.
To exemplify:

```
TextField AdditionalInfo: 

YAY!

I'm stuck!

Please Help me!
```

The program will terminate with an error message "No line found", because
"YAY!" will be assigned to an info String and complete a previous Value class.
"I'm stuck!" will be assigned to a name String, and "Please Help me!" to a date String and a Value class will be called, however it can't be created because it requires three parameters(name, date, info) and the program provides only two(name and date).
How may I store data in a file differently, so that when the file is being scanned, the String name assigns only the value from the file that represents name, String date only date info, and String info only additional information, which includes everything that a user typed?

Comment: You'll need to sanitize input as early as you can, probably before `updateFile()` Pleas [edit] your question with a [mcve] that focuses on that aspect of the problem.

Comment: Use a structured format to store the data, e.g. json or XML.  This is relatively straightforward with the assistance of libraries such as [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) (there is a section in the linked doc specifically for date formatting which is part of your question).  Also review the [makery tutorial](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/) to see how that reference application performs a similar task.

Comment: I really like JSON and XML, but for a simple app, I would recommend CSV or TSV formats. My personal favorite that no one recommends for simple projects is using [`RECORD SEPARATOR`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/241e/index.htm). It helps do away with a lot of problems associated with using `Tabs` or `Commas` separated files.

Comment: Also, stay away from `Scanner` if you don't have to use it. If you go with CSV, TSV, or RSV, you can use `Files.readAllLines` to read the lines to a `List`. From there you just split on the separator. For a simple program, you can probably get away with this for CSV and TSV. If it's a serious program, I recommend using a CSV or TSV library.

Comment: I think the choice of structured format is not as important in this case as just having one.  json/xml/csv/yaml, whatever, backed up by a solid parser (recommended to use a library implementation not something you write yourself) are all fine.   If you want to hammer a nail, having a hammer is helpful, the choice of hammer color is less functionally important, though the color is an important aesthetic (I like red and silver ones).  So choose a format, try to implement it, and, if you get stuck, produce a new question with limited scope and a [mcve] with your attempt.